# Android: ImageView's Location Changes on different sizes screen

Tags: android, xml, layout, imageview

I have five image views in my layout and I should put every image view on specific location on the background. When running my app on different screen sizes, Locations of image views are shifted up.
I create the following folders.
res/layout- small
res/layout-normal
res/layout-large
res/layout-xlarge
Here you will find my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:background="@drawable/upn">

       <ImageView
            android:layout_width="45dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:id="@+id/U1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#f40c0d"
            android:padding="1dip"
           android:layout_marginRight="26dip"
           android:layout_marginEnd="26dip"
           android:layout_marginBottom="96dip"
           android:layout_above="@+id/U5"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="45dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:id="@+id/U3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#f40c0d"
            android:padding="1dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="63dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="63dip"
            android:layout_above="@+id/U1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/U1"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/U1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="22dip" />


       <ImageView
            android:layout_width="45dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:id="@+id/U2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#f40c0d"
            android:padding="1dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="103dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/U3"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/U3"
           />

       <ImageView
             android:layout_width="45dip"
             android:layout_height="20dip"
             android:id="@+id/U4"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:background="#f40c0d"
             android:padding="1dip"
           android:layout_above="@+id/U2"
           android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/U5"
           android:layout_alignStart="@+id/U5"
           android:layout_marginBottom="18dip"
           />

         <ImageView
             android:layout_width="45dip"
             android:layout_height="20dip"
             android:id="@+id/U5"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:background="#f40c0d"
             android:padding="1dip"
             android:layout_marginLeft="68dip"
             android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
             android:layout_above="@+id/U2"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
             android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that those names are not correct for the layouts.

Comment: just one image for each layout? than u just need 5 different layouts with one image view .. each layout should contain the same imageview ID

Comment: @durbnpoisn ,I get those folder names from here [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels)

Comment: @AlexanderSidikov, I don't get your idea. Do you mean I have to put every image view in Relative Layout then I will get five Relative Layouts inside Relative layout whose ID = body.

Answer (score 0):

> res/layout/your_layout.xml    *//layout for normal screen size("default")*
>
> res/layout-large/your_layout.xml  *//layout for large screen size*
>
> res/layout-xlarge/your_layout.xml *//layout for extra-large screen size*
>
> res/layout-xlarge-land/your_layout.xml  *//layout for extra-large in landscape orientation*

and in each folder ..the a your_layout.xml with different image positions

*eg. res/layout_large/your_layout.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:background="@drawable/upn">

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_iv"
         .....
   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

maybe you have to add this lines in your manifest file

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
          android:normalScreens="true" 
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:xlargeScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true" />
```

//More informations:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

> Provide different layouts for different screen sizes
>   By default, Android resizes your application layout to fit the current device screen. In most cases, this works fine. In other cases, your UI might not look as good and might need adjustments for different screen sizes. For example, on a larger screen, you might want to adjust the position and size of some elements to take advantage of the additional screen space, or on a smaller screen, you might need to adjust sizes so that everything can fit on the screen.
>   **The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge. For example, layouts for an extra large screen should go in layout-xlarge/.**
>   Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups are deprecated and you should instead use the sw<N>dp configuration qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your layout resources. For example, if your multi-pane tablet layout requires at least 600dp of screen width, you should place it in **layout-sw600dp/**. Using the new techniques for declaring layout resources is discussed further in the section about Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2.